# Centred Image in DIV

Tags: image, html, center

CSS:

```
overlay { 
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0px; 
  left: 0px; 
  z-index: 99999; 
  background-color:black; 
  filter: alpha(opacity=75); 
  -moz-opacity: 0.75; 
  opacity: 0.75; 
}
overlay h2 { 
  position: fixed; 
  margin-left: 40%; 
  top: 40%; 
  font-size: 1.75em; 
  font-weight:700; 
  color:#EF9C00;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="overlay"><h2>Loading.. Please wait</h2></div>
```

I'd like to a loader.png to appear directly under the words on the next line centred.
Everything I try seems to put the image over the text or to the right of it !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right img loading :

```
<div id="overlay"><h2>Loading.. Please wait <img src="http://jimpunk.net/Loading/wp-content/uploads/loading23.gif" /></h2></div>
```

add this css

```
#overlay  img {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Next line centred img loading :

```
<div id="overlay">
  <h2>
    Loading.. Please wait <br /><img src="http://jimpunk.net/Loading/wp-     content/uploads/loading23.gif" />
  </h2>
</div>
```

Add this css

```
#overlay h2 { 
      text-align:center;
}
```